# My isupper function always says it is not upper

Tags: c

I can't seem to figure out why my output is only one-fold.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
int my_isupper(int c);
int my_tolower(int c);

int
main(int argc,char *argv[]){
int c;
printf("Enter alphabet:");
scanf("%d",&c);
if ((c<='A' && c>='Z')||(c<='a' && c>='z')){
    printf("Error: Please type a alphabet\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (my_isupper(c)==0){
   printf("isnotupper");
}
else{
   printf("is upper");
}
return 0;
}
int my_isupper(int c){
if(c>='A' && c<='Z'){
   return 1;
}
else {
   return 0;
}
}
```

The output is always "Isnotupper". Might be a simple error. I'm new to c programming. If you have any tips on debugging, please tell me so that I won't bother anyone with things I can self-correct.
Thanks!

Comment: The logic is wrong in `if ((c<='A' && c>='Z')||(c<='a' && c>='z')){` : this will never be satisfied. Swap the `&&` with `||` and remove all the `=`.

Answer (score 5):

```
int c;
printf("Enter alphabet:");
scanf("%d",&c);
```

should be

```
char c;
printf("Enter alphabet:");
scanf("%c",&c);
```

You need to scan an alphabet not an integer. Going by your code you expect the user to input alphabet and if you enter an alphabet the `scanf()`(previous one with `%d`) will fail.
So always check the `scanf()` return value.

```
if(scanf("%c",&c) == 1)
//Do you stuff
else
//Throw an error
```

Comment: And check the return value of `scanf` to make sure that there are no errors in reading the data.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the format specifiers, you also need to adjust your test from:

```
((c<='A' && c>='Z')||(c<='a' && c>='z'))
```

to

```
((c<'A' || c>'Z') && (c<'a' || c>'z'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Statements such as:

```
if ((c<='A' && c>='Z')||(c<='a' && c>='z')){
```

tend to be buggy. It will be easier if you put the logic in functions.

```
if ( !is_alphabet(c) ) {
```

Where:

```
int is_lower_alphabet(int c)
{
   return ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int is_upper_alphabet(int c)
{
   return ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}

int is_alphabet(int c)
{
    return (is_lower_alphabet(c) || is_upper_alhabet(c));
}
```